# I am trying to run a batch job in flink project and i am getting this Error: Could not build the program from JAR file

Tags: apache-flink

These are the things i do:

```
1)mvn clean install 
2) mvn package 
3) ./bin/start-cluster.sh 
4)./bin/flink run -q .project-flink-2.jar  
5) ./bin/stop-cluster.sh
```

Comment: Did you try to run one of the flink examples? If not how does your main method looks like?

Comment: Please check the logs for the full exception and post it here. It is possible that your jar does not have a correct main class MANIFEST entry. You could try pointing Flink to your exact main class using the -c option. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/ops/cli.html#examples